# press and hold home button to see all running apps in teamviewer quick support

Tags: teamviewer

I use [teamviewer quick support](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=en)  to control my mom's android from my mac.

It works ok. But still can't figure out how to press and hold home button to see all running apps in android using my mac's trackpad or keyboard.

I tried to move mouse over home button and press left mouse long and tried right mouse key but there is no result.

[image: how to press and hold home button to see all running apps in teamviewer quick support]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can install an app that emulate it. For example application *home button* . After installation long press to show the recent apps. Application *floating toucher * has an option named **recent app**